# Using Microsoft.XMLHTTP in classic ASP to post JSON results in blank content

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

This has been baffling me for a while. 
I'm trying to post JSON content to a webhook but need to use Classic ASP. 
I can do it using jquery but needs to be serverside. 
I've also tried using JScript which results in the same issue. Also tried a separate server

The script fundamentally works, If I set the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the posted content comes through fine, but as soon as I change to `application/json` the content disappears (the request makes it though as I can inspect the headers at the other end)

```
strEnvelope = "{""content"":""Serverside Test Post"",""embeds"": [{""description"":""Now to grab and extract content""}]}"
data = "content="&Server.URLEncode(strEnvelope)

dim xmlhttp 
set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST","https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/000000000000/key",false
'xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xmlhttp.send(data)
Response.Write xmlhttp.ResponseText
Set xmlhttp = nothing
```

Any thoughts much appreciated, it's weird as all I'm doing is changing the `Content-Type` header

Comment: You could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15818268/1682881) to access the posted json.

Comment: Thanks for the response @SearchAndResQ, that seems to be about reading the response, my problem was it wasn't posting anything at all. 
However, it seems to be working now (my update is below)

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't know why, but it's started working.

Initially, I tried creating the json string via stringify function (JSON Parser written by Fabio Zendhi Nagao if you want to google) and noticed it working.

But then I noticed some other earlier tests working.

At the moment I'm putting it down to to the inclusion of:

`xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept","application/json"`

However, this was in earlier tests which failed - It's now working so I ain't complaining :-)